# Parent exception class of all selenium exceptions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my existing project, I've code like following -

```
public static boolean isSessionAvailable(WebDriver driver){
    try{
        driver.getTitle();
        return true;
    }
    catch(UnreachableBrowserException s){
        return false;
    }
    catch(NoSuchWindowException s){
        return false;
    }
    catch(Throwable t){
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm planning to refactor it. Currently not sure what all exceptions try block can throw. As far as I can see `WebDriverException` is parent of all these possible exceptions. In that case, could you please confirm if following is correct refactored coded.(Note. I could also have used multi exceptions catch functionally which is separated by |)

```
    public static boolean isSessionAvailable(WebDriver driver){
     try{
        driver.getTitle();
        return true;
     }
     catch(WebDriverException wde){
        return false;
     }
   }
```

I can use `Exception` or `Throwable` but that is more generic instead of specific.

Comment: Asking for clarification here ... was my answer helpful, or are some details missing for you? Just wondering, as you didn't provide any feedback or accept or so.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, your two code snippets are **not** doing the same thing.

The first code catches `Throwable`, thus **nothing** should be able to "escape" from that method.

Whereas your refactored code allows for example that `RuntimeException`s will bubble up to client code that invokes `isSessionAvailable()`..

You ask whether that is "correct", but we can't tell you that.

Because "correct" is based on your requirements. If that method is required to never throw, then your refactoring is wrong. But if there is no such requirement: then your code is fine.

Beyond that, it feels the real answer is: you should research exception handling in Java. Because **you** should understand each and any line you put down in your classes.

Finally: I suggest that you also look into adding some kind of logging. Your code basically ignores all kinds of errors. Which makes it really hard later on to understand what is going on.